# Not able to install Ionic app while another ionic app installed on device?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app designed and installed in my device, when I try installing another ionic app designed I am getting "App not Installed" message.

I have changed widget id in config.xml and also changed in manifest.xml as well. But no luck. Any help on this?

```
<widget android-versionCode="201018" 
        id="edc.dev.education" 
        version="2.2.1" 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Like to avoid "APP NOT INSTALLED" issue.

Comment: You might be using the same namespace to develop your apps. Each app must have a unique namespace to be installed.

Comment: Where I can find the name space, is it in config.xml file